# How to get input from multiple machine for spark streaming?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

As per example given in Spark for streaming, it takes input by connecting as a client, through netcat server (nc -lk 9999).

However, netcat is limited to handle only single client. What if I want to send streaming data from multiple servers?

Can someone give me working example for this? I am using pyspark.

Answer (score 0):

There are several options to solving this, one is using something like Kafka (see the Spark Streaming Kafka docs http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/streaming-kafka-integration.html ), another would be setting up multiple simple network socket receivers and using the `union` function on the DStreams.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I'll try Kafka with Pyspark.

Comment: the above link has java and scala. any other link for doing the same with python?

Answer (score 0):

You can create multiple streams with deferent hosts and ports, and then union these streams to one. I have example code of multiple Kafka receivers as following:

```
val sparkContet = new SparkContext(sparkConf)
val ssc = new StreamingContext(sparkContet, Seconds(BATCH_TIME.toInt))
//create 5 streams
val receivers = (1 to 5).map(i => KafkaUtils.createStream(ssc, kafkaParams, topicMap, StorageLevel.MEMORY_AND_DISK_SER_2))
val unionedStreaming = ssc.union(receivers)  
val mapDstream = unionedStreaming.map(_._2)
```